# Silverlight Parent Usercontrol Resources access

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, resources, parent

a simple question

it's possibile for a usercontrol, to view (directly in xaml) Parent resources?

for example e usercontrol contains

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewModel:ExampleResource x:Key="ExampleResourcex1"></viewModel:ExampleResourcex>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and a usercontrol inside him, need to reference and bind ExampleResourcex1 as StaticResource

It's possible?

Thanks

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Static resources can be defined at any level and are visible to anything below that level using static resource binding.

We often put our converters into App.xaml instead of in pages as they can be seen by everything app-wide.

Comment: if i put a resource in father, and a child usercontrol derectly reference it, i have a resource not found exception...possible?